# Why am I not getting the right mathematical output?

Tags: python, math

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
rate = input("Enter rate per hour:")
h = float(hrs)
r = float(rate)
if h > 40:
    overtime_pay = float((h % 40)) * float((1.5 * r))
gross_pay = float((h * r)) + float(overtime_pay)
print(gross_pay)
```

```
hrs = 45
rate = 10.50
```

I need to calculate the gross pay, including overtime

Gross_pay should be 497.85 but I'm getting 551.25
I can't tell if I'm just coding it wrong or if my math skills are lacking.

Comment: If I work 45 hours total, then 5 of those should be overtime and 40 should be billed normally. Your program bills 5 of them as overtime and 45 normally.

Comment: I carried out the calculation in a calculator following what you have written here and got back `551.25`.

You may want to make sure that `h` is being capped at 40

Answer (score 0):

First, by my calculation, the gross pay should be $498.75, not $497.85. Second, calculating `h % 40` will cause problems if h is greater than 40, so it should be `h - 40` instead. Your biggest problem, however, is that you include hours beyond the 40th in your calculation of base pay, even though those are already accounted for via overtime_pay. A simple solution would be to replace `h * 4` with `min(h, 40) * 4` in your final calculation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).